# How to install ckanext-wet-boew as ckan extension?

Tags: python, ckan

I'm trying to add "ckanext-wet-boew" ckanext to my ckan 2.2.
These are the steps I followed:

1.- Download the zip file from: https://github.com/open-data/ckanext-wet-boew
2.- Extract to a folder.
3.- Create a folder in /usr/lib/ckan/default/src called: ckanext-wet_boew
4.- Copy the content from the subfolder ckanext-wet-boew-master\ckanext-wet-boew-master to ckanext-wet_boew
5.- As it say in readme.st I add wet-boew-dist-3.1.7 and I download jqueymobile1.3.2 to folder
6.- Now as it says in: http://docs.ckan.org/en/1117-start-new-test-suite/writing-extensions.html
there is a note: "To instead install a python package by copying all of the files to the site-packages directory run python setup.py install"

With this steps it should be possible to use this plugin adding in `production.ini` ckan.plugins = ...   wet_theme

As it fail I have done 
python `setup.py` develop

but no way.
Any idea???
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When installed, and after unzipping the wet-boew dist zip file, your file directory should look something like this:

```
ckanext-wet_boew/
  README.rst
  setup.py
  ckanext/
    wet_boew/
      plugins.py
      templates/
      theme/
      public/
        en/
        fr/
        images
        readme.rst
        dist/
          ckan/
          grids/
          js/
          resource.config
          theme-base/
          theme-clf2-nsi2/
          theme-gcwu-fegc/
          theme-gcwu-intranet/
          theme-ogpl/
          theme-wet-boew/
```

If the files aren't in this structure, the extension will not work.

After running "python setup.py develop" on the setup.py in the root folder, the package should be available for use.

Comment: Hi.

Thanks,  I have checked your structure and after re-install and run python setup.py develop  it seems to works (Not exactly why). 

Unfortunately web responsive not works as expected. Not sure about jquery mobile version or what.

thanks